# MySQL sort ordered grouped data

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime, subquery, sql-order-by

I have two tables: ticket and ticketRules and i have a query like this:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT * FROM ticketRules
    ORDER BY
        date DESC,
        time DESC
) AS myTicketRules
GROUP BY ticketId
ORDER BY ticketId ASC
```

The first `Order By` (the one in the subquery) sorts data by date and time so the last ticketrule is always the first.
I group the results by `ticketId` so I only got the last ticketRule for each ticket.
Now I want to sort the results by ticket but if I do that the first result is also affected and tickets don't have the last ticketrule anymore but the one with the lowest id cause it's ordered by ticketId.

How can I sort only the visible records after I grouped them?

Comment: If you're still struggling see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Do you want the complete row in your result or just the max date/time?

Answer (score 1):

There are several issues with your query :

- there should be only one ORDER BY clause (that should be placed in the outer query)
- GROUP BY does not do what you think (ie it does not give access to the last ticket)

If you are trying to pull out the full latest record for each ticketId, ordered by ticketId, you can use a correlated subquery as follows :

```
SELECT 
    t.*
FROM
    ticketrule t
WHERE
    t.date = (
        SELECT MAX(date)
        FROM ticketrule
        WHERE ticketId = t.ticketId 
    )
ORDER BY t.ticketId
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The struggle with my table is that i use 2 seperate tables for date and time (for design purposes) so the MAX() function doesn't work for me. Any ideas how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

you should not use a  group by without aggregation function and for obtain the last value  could use use an aggregation function as `max( )`

```
select  ticketId, max(date)
from ticketRules 
grouo by ticketId
```